# how to send contact us form to mail box from iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have a contact us form in my iphone application.
        with first name last email phone no. and Message field
   I want to send this information to email adress say abc.gmail.com
can any body guide me how to do this.
 i have tried a [tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2009/02/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-openurl-to-send-email-from-your-app/) it working but mail is not receiving to my mail box.
can any body help me or send me the code sample for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is perfect but the simulator has certain constraints.

You `CANNOT` send mails through simulator even though it says mail send sucessfully.

So for sending mails you have to install the application on device and test.

Try MFMAILCOMPOSER.